# Programmatically create a term?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, 8

I'm attempting to add a lot of terms (~200) to a vocabulary, but I can't find any import modules that are updated for Drupal 8, and it seems the functions for doing this in Drupal 7 don't exist in Drupal 8. So, can anyone point me in the right direction for doing this?

I attempted to do it with `entity_create`, as suggested in the comments, with this code:

```
$term_create = entity_create('taxonomy_term', array('name' => 'test', 'vocabulary_name' => 'client'));
```

but I got this error:

```
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException: Missing bundle for entity type taxonomy_term in Drupal\Core\Entity\FieldableEntityStorageControllerBase->create() (line 65 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/FieldableEntityStorageControllerBase.php).
```

Any ideas?

Comment: A term is an entity, so...[`entity_create()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!includes!entity.inc/function/entity_create/8)

Comment: I attempted to do this with this code: `$term_create = entity_create('taxonomy_term', array('name' => 'test', 'vocabulary_name' => 'client'));`, but I got the error `Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException: Missing bundle for entity type taxonomy_term in Drupal\Core\Entity\FieldableEntityStorageControllerBase->create() (line 65 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/FieldableEntityStorageControllerBase.php).` -- Any ideas?

Comment: Try `vid` in place of `vocabulary_name`. Looks like the column is still `vid` in `taxonomy_term_data`, but it's the vocab name instead of id now

Comment: The entity data should not be derived from the SQL tables, see below.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You know that you want something from taxonomy module so first you need to look in `Drupal\taxonomy\Entity` -- or the corresponding directory -- you will find the `Term` class there. Now look at the annotation, it says `@ContentEntityType` and in there:

```
*   entity_keys = {
*     "id" = "tid",
*     "bundle" = "vid",
*     "label" = "name",
*     "uuid" = "uuid"
*   },
```

So, what you want is

```
$term = Term::create([
  'name' => 'test', 
  'vid' => 'client',
])->save();
```

because the `label` entity key is `name` and the `bundle` entity key is `vid`. I added a `->save()` call as well as I presume you wanted to save it too.

Comment: More options are available over at http://www.drupal8.ovh/en/tutoriels/55/create-taxonomy-term-programmatically-on-drupal-8.

Comment: `$term = \Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term::create(array(
 'name' => 'whatever',
 'vid' => 'tags',
));
$term->save();` gives me Fatal error: Call to undefined method Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term::getType

Comment: yes, it's working well..

Answer (score 15):

At this time you should add term in little bit another way (in compare with [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/108868#answer-108874) answer)
First of all in your file begin you should write

> use Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term;

Because Term class listed in Drupal\taxonomy\Entity.
And you don't need to pass taxonomy_term parametr to

> Term::create

because only one parametr is needed (array with values) (below listed code for this method in taxonomy module)

```
public function create(array $values = array()) {
  // Save new terms with no parents by default.
  if (empty($values['parent'])) {
    $values['parent'] = array(0);
  }
  $entity = parent::create($values);
  return $entity;
}
```

So the final example is

```
use Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term;
$categories_vocabulary = 'blog_categories'; // Vocabulary machine name
$categories = ['test 1', 'test 2', 'test 3', 'test 4']; // List of test terms
foreach ($categories as $category) {
  $term = Term::create(array(
    'parent' => array(),
    'name' => $category,
    'vid' => $categories_vocabulary,
  ))->save();
}
```

Comment: Something you may want to know. $term will be equal to 1 most likely because `Entity::save()` returns an int. Either the constants `SAVED_NEW` or `SAVED_UPDATED` depending on the operation performed. However, if you were to remove the `->save()` and add `$term->save();`, you will then see that `$term` is updated with the information that was saved to the database. Example you can now do `$tid = $term->tid->value;`

Answer (score 9):

With `entityTypeManager()`:

```
$term = [
  'name'     => $name,
  'vid'      => $vocabulary,
  'langcode' => $language,
];

$term = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->create($term);
```

Comment: `save()` doesn't return the entity object, so `$term = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->create($term)->save()`; is wrong, as it would store in `$term` an integer, not an entity object.

Comment: \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->create($term)->save()' will return the status (an integer indeed 0 or 1) but it works for saving the term. If you wish to use the term as well, you need to create() first (returns the term entity) and then $term->save()

Answer (score 8):

```
Term::create([
 'name' => 'Lama',
 'vid' => $vocabulary_id,
]);
```

The other answers use `entity_create()`, which works, but is not quite as nice as the OOP approach.

Answer (score 7):

Before creating a term, it's better to check if it's exist, here is the code:

```
use Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term;

if ($terms = taxonomy_term_load_multiple_by_name($term_value, 'vocabulary')) {
  // Only use the first term returned; there should only be one anyways if we do this right.
  $term = reset($terms);
} else {
  $term = Term::create([
    'name' => $term_value,
    'vid' => 'vocabulary',
  ]);
  $term->save();
}
$tid = $term->id();
```

Source: https://www.btmash.com/article/2016-04-26/saving-and-retrieving-taxonomy-terms-programmatically-drupal-8

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at how devel/devel_generate does this.

From [devel_generate](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21devel%21devel_generate%21devel_generate.inc/function/devel_generate_terms/8) :

```
$values['name'] = devel_generate_word(mt_rand(2, $maxlength));
$values['description'] = "description of " . $values['name'];
$values['format'] = filter_fallback_format();
$values['weight'] = mt_rand(0, 10);
$values['langcode'] = LANGUAGE_NOT_SPECIFIED;
$term = entity_create('taxonomy_term', $values);
```